# Best way to create an interactable grid

Tags: java, android, view

What I want is a little unusual. I want to make a screen that shows me a number squares inside of it. I should be able to determine the number of rows and lines by two integers. I also want to be able to set for example colors of the squares, and they should be clickable so they need to have an id that is numbered and an onClick function.

For example:

```
height=2
rows=3
color1=FFFFFF
color5=000000
```

is Something like this achievable? How should I approach this?

Comment: Sounds achievable.  Unfortunately "how do I approach X?" is too broad a question for SO.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a JButton.

For your particular problem, consider creating a 2D Array of JButtons and display them using a JPanel and JFrame. The size height and width of your grid would be the length of each of these arrays. E.g.

myArray.length() is the width (number of columns in the grid) and myArray[0].length() is the height of the grid (number of rows).

JButton supports setting images and colours.

Documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html